# mysqldump returning unknown variable sql-mode error

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error when I run mysqldump like this:

```
$ mysqldump -u my_user -pXXX -h 127.0.0.1 --databases my_db > db_backup.sql
mysqldump: unknown variable 'sql-mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

Does anyone know what could be going on?

I also get the same thing when I try to start the MySQL client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I had "sql-mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES" in the client settings section of my my.cnf file.  I moved it to the server section and it seems all good.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad line in your .my.conf file, or maybe one of your system .ini files.